# A reversible transformation, but there is finite temperature heat transfer?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, definition, reversibility

Suppose to have 3 heat reservoirs, the first at temperature $T_1$, the second at temperature $T_1+dT$ and the third at temperature $T_2>T_1$

Then, consider a system, which volume is constant, in thermal equilibrium with the colder reservoir, $T_{system}=T_1$, and do the following steps (order matters):

1. put the system in contact with the hotter reservoir, and wait until $T_{system}=T_2$
2. put the system in contact with the reservoir at temperature $T_1+dT$ and wait until $T_{system}=T_1+dT$

Note that, the thermodynamic equilibrium state of the system, at the initial condition point, is infinitesimally close to that of point, 2. So, considering those two equilibrium states, we can write :

$dE=TdS-PdV=Q+W$

However, since $dV=0$ by assumption, and $W=0$:

$dE=TdS=Q$, that means $dS=Q/T$.

Since the last relation holds only for reversible processes, the transformation is reversible. This seams paradoxical, because in the transformation there is heat transfer with finite temperature difference.

EDIT:

Why don't we get rid of the reservoir at $T_1+dT$ and just bring the system back into contact with the first reservoir?

The reservoir at $T_1+dT$ is a ploy to write down differentials and obtain $Q/T = dS$. Clausius inequality states $Q/T \leq dS$, where the equality hold for reversible transformation. So, since, here $Q/T = dS$, the transformation seems to be reversible.

EDIT:

Thanks you, i figure out that i was wrong, the transformation is not irreversible. I was confused about the expression $\delta Q/T$, that, many times, is written in an ambiguous way. I think the following recap about $\delta Q/T$ could be useful.

- $dS =\delta Q_{rev} /T$ is the t**hermodynamic definition of entropy**.
  Note that, for a heat exchange to be reversible, temperature
  differences must be infinitesimal, so, $T=T_{surr}$, and, $dS =\delta
     Q_{rev} /T$ is equivalent to $dS =\delta Q_{rev} /T_{surr}$
- $dS \ge \delta Q_{real}/T_{surr}$ is the **Clausius inequality**, where
  the equality holds **only** for reversible transformation. So, if
  $dS=\delta Q/T_{surr}$, the transformation is reversible, that means
  $T=T_{surr}$, that means $dS=\delta Q/T_{surr}$
- It's important to note that $dS=\delta Q/T$ doesn't imply
  reversibility, because there are transformations in which $T \neq T_{surr}$, as in the example above. But, $dS=\delta Q/T_{surr}$
  imply reversibility, and, in this case, $dS=\delta Q/T$, is also true

Comment: The $T$ in the Clausius inequality is *not* equal to the temperature of the system.  It's the temperature of the immediate *environment* of the system (or the boundary of the system in an analysis where you're using a control volume).

Comment: The last edit is almost fine, except I would not write the "rev" in $\delta Q_{rev}$. The formula $dS = dQ/T$ is sometimes valid even when $dQ$ is exchanged during a process that is overall (when looking at the whole supersystem) *irreversible*. The decisive factor is, is the system going only through equilibrium states (then the formula holds) or not (then it need not hold, especially when there is no single temperature $T$).

Comment: @JánLalinský Consider an irreversible transformation in which $dS=\delta Q_{irr}/T$ holds, as the one in the example above. Even in this case, i could device a reversible transformation, that connects the same initial and final equilibrium states, and write, $dS= \delta Q_{rev}/T$. In this case, $dS=\delta Q_{irr}/T=\delta Q_{rev}/T$

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the last relation holds only for reversible processes, the transformation is reversible.

No, that process involving $T_2$ is not reversible, because it involves irreversible transfer of heat from body of temperature $T_2$ to body of different temperature $T_1$.

The relation

$$
dS = \frac{dQ}{T},
$$
where $S$ is entropy of the system studied and $T$ is its temperature, holds true also when the system partakes in *some* irreversible processes.

E.g. consider a process involving slow enough heat acceptance from a hotter reservoir, so that temperature of the system changes only slowly and remains uniform throughout the system, so it always has single temperature $T$. System's internal energy is function of entropy and volume $U(S,V)$, and the process can be such that all variables $U,S,T,P$ are defined at every instant (quasi-static process) while the system accepts heat from the hotter body. Then $dS$ and $dV$ define $dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S}dS - \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}dV$. If no change of volume and no work is allowed, $dU$ is equal to $dQ$ and thus $dQ$ is determined by $dS$ to be $TdS$; it can't be chosen arbitrarily by choosing some different path in the space of equilibrium states, because the path is fixed by the condition $dV = 0$.

You are probably confused by the fact there is also the general relation (assuming single source of heat)

$$
dS \geq \frac{dQ}{T_r}
$$
where $T_r$ is temperature of the source of heat (reservoir). This can be sharpened/replaced by equality for any part of the process that is reversible (and then $T_r=T$). For irreversible transformations, the equality may not be valid, that's why we write defensively the unsharp inequality; but the equality is also not forbidden to be valid, especially if we change the formula by putting in $T$ instead of $T_r$.

Comment: Please provide an example of an irreversible process of a closed system for which dS=dQ/T, and, in an irreversible process involving spatial temperature variations within the system, which T value would you use?

Comment: @ChetMiller Let there be a hot metal cube 2 and a cold metal cube 1, both connected with each other by a long wooden beam of negligible heat capacity, otherwise all objects are thermally insulated. Heat will pass from the hotter cube to the colder one, but very slowly, so both cubes will maintain uniform temperature (independent of position within the cube). For the cold cube we have $dS_1 = dQ/T_1$, for the hot cube $dS_2 = -dQ/T_2$, and for the cold cube we can also write the famous inequality as $dS_1 > dQ/T_2$ ($T_2$ being temperature of the source of heat).

Comment: If there are variations of temperature within the system, such as there are in the whole combined system cube+beam+cube, then there is no single $T$. If there was another source of heat with temperature $T_3$, and the combined system accepted heat $Q'$ from it, we could write the famous inequality as $dS_{cube,rod,cube} \geq dQ'/T_3$.

Comment: @JánLalinský thanks for your answer, it cleared up many doubts for me. I've edited the question, to recap the main concepts, about $\delta Q /T$, that i figured out form this answer. Can you check if they are correct?

Comment: In the 2-cube and wooden beam example you gave, each of the cubes can be treated as a closed system, each experiencing individually an essentially reversible process with $\Delta S=Q_{cube}/T_{cube}$.  All the irreversibility takes place within the wooden beam, which receives entropy from the hot cube and discharges a greater amount of entropy to the cold cube.

Comment: @ChetMiller Indeed. But both cubes take part in the overall irreversible process where entropy is generated, while it is not generated inside those cubes. So validity of the formula $dS=dQ/T$ for a subsystem does not hinge upon the overall process reversibility, only on the assumption the subsystem moves through equilibrium states. I suppose we can say that subsystem undergoes a process that from inside looks exactly like reversible process, even though overall the process is not reversible.

Comment: However I don't think calling the process the cold cube undergoes *reversible* is a good communication, because it goes against the very definition of "thermodynamically reversible process". Even though the cube temperature is uniform and no entropy is generated inside it, there is no way, by changing the conditions infinitesimally, to revert the heat flow so that it would be flowing away from the cold cube to the beam to the hot cube.

Comment: Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics refer to an Internally Reversible Process as  "one for which there are no irreversibilities within the system."  This definition applies to each of the two cubes.

Comment: I encounter certain kind of argument from time to time, often from narrow domain experts, that terminology used by the domain experts or authoritative resources is the correct one to use always, and they downplay its deficiencies. On this site the primary aim is to share/teach physics concepts, not merely expert terminology, and thus teacher should select the best expression to communicate ideas to the students. Thus not necessarily always using the "correct definitions" used by the experts, especially when they are confusing.

Comment: I think "internally reversible" is a useful term, but it is also useful to just plainly say here that validity of $dS=dQ/T$ does not require reversible process.

Answer (score 3):

The equation dU=TdS-PdV holds for any pair of closely neighboring thermodynamic equilibrium states, even if they represent the starting and end points for an irreversible path.  If you had devised a reversible path between the same two end points, you would have obtained the same entropy change, which is essentially what you did.

Comment: sorry, i think the question was not clear, i edited the post enlightening that, the point of my question, is that $dS=Q/T$ only for reversible trasformations

Comment: For the irreversible process you considered, $$\Delta S>\frac{Q}{T_2}-\frac{Q}{T_1}$$where $Q=mc(T_2-T_1)$ which satisfies the Clausius Inequality

Comment: ok, but from the differentials in my question, it seems that $dS=Q/T$

Comment: are you suggesting that $dS=Q/T$ can hold also for non reversible transformations?

Comment: The Q/T you wrote is not the integral of $\int{dQ/T_{boundaary}}$ for the irreversible path you defined.

Comment: sorry, for bothering you,  can you explain this in more details? i think this comment is  the kind of answer i was searching

Comment: The Clausius inequality should properly read $$\Delta S>\int{\frac{dQ}{T_{boundary}}}$$where $T_{boundary }$ is the temperature at the system boundary through which the heat flow dQ takes pace.

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler example of the same thing, get rid of the reservoir at $T_1+dT$ and just bring the system back into contact with the first reservoir. You now have a cyclic process, where the final state is the same as the initial state, and so must have the same entropy (and so $dS=dQ/T=0$), but if the process of irreversible then entropy must have increased. The solution is that we have neglected the entropy of the reservoir at $T_2$, which will have increased during the various heat transfer processes

Comment: I think you meant that the entropy of T2 reservoir decreases by less than the entropy of T1 reservoir increases.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think the  question was not clear, so i edited it. Indeed, yes, i see that it's not reversible, this is why it is strange. But the core of the question is that $dS=Q/T$ only for reversible transformations, so, according to Clausius inequelity, it should be reversible